# PHP recursion with the results put into a single array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I am trying to program a web crawler but I have no idea, how to create a recursion for parsing a webpage and adding all the endresults into a final array.
I never worked with php before but I did alot of research on the internet and figured already out, how to parse the page I want to scrape.

 Please note, that I have changed the $url value and the array result below to some values which I have randomly generated in my mind.

```php
<?php
include_once "simple_html_dom.php"; //http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

$url = "https://www.scrapesite.com/pagetoscrape/index.html";

function parseLink($link) {
    $html = file_get_html($link);
    $html = $html->find("/html/body/script[2]/text", 0);
    preg_match('/\{(?:[^{}]|(?R))*\}/', $html, $matches); //this regex extracts a json array
    $json = json_decode($matches[0]);
    $data = ($json->props->contents);
    return $data;
}
function getFolders($basepath, $data) {
    $data = $data->folders;
    $result = array();

    foreach ($data as $value) {
        $result[] = array("folder", $basepath . "/" . $value->filename, $value->href);
    }

    return $result;
}

$data = getFolders("", parseLink($url));
print_r ($data);

?>
```

This script works fine and it outputs the following:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => folder
            [1] => /1
            [2] => https://www.scrapesite.com/pagetoscrape/sjdfi327943sad/index.html
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => folder
            [1] => /2
            [2] => https://www.scrapesite.com/pagetoscrape/345fdsjjsdfsdf/index.html
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => folder
            [1] => /3
            [2] => https://www.scrapesite.com/pagetoscrape/46589dsjodsiods/index.html
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => folder
            [1] => /4
            [2] => https://www.scrapesite.com/pagetoscrape/345897dujfosfsd/index.html
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => folder
            [1] => /5
            [2] => https://www.scrapesite.com/pagetoscrape/9dsfghshdfsds3/index.html
        )

)
```

Now, the script should execute the getFolders function for every item in the above array. This may return another array of folder which should get parsed too.
And then I want to create a final array where all the folders ABSOLUTE paths ($basepath . "/" . $value->filename) and href links are listed. 
I really appreciate every little hint.
I was able to find some example on the web but I can't figure out how to implement it here because I have almost no experience with programming languages in general.

Comment: Can you tell what expected outcome you want from this `This script works fine and it outputs the following array`?

Comment: For example in [0] of the array there is [2], which is a link. Basicly, I want to do the getFolders function with all the links in [2].
But it should be truely recursive. So If said function is executed through all the links in the array it should do it for the resulting link too and again and again (recursive). And in the process there should result a final array of all the links and corrosponding pathes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize an empty array and pass that as a reference to the `getFolders()` function. Keep putting the results of scraping inside this array. Also, you need to call `getFolders()` again inside the `foreach` loop of the `getFolders()`. Example below:

```
$finalResults = array();
getFolders("", parseLink($url), $finalResults);
```

Your `getFolders()` function signature will now look like below:

```
function getFolders($basepath, $data, &$finalResults) //notice the & before the $finalResults used for passing by reference
```

And, your foreach loop:

```
foreach ($data as $value) {
    $finalResults[] = array("folder", $basepath . "/" . $value->filename, $value->href);
    getFolders("", parseLink($value->href), $finalResults);
}
```

Above code is just an example. Change it according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks alot, this is exactly what I wanted (the recursion). I modified the code a bit to update the $basepath and now everything is working. You are my hero :)